# while loop result at table, sends first row when submit form in php

Tags: php, forms, while-loop, submit

1.fetch user data and display in tabular fashion

```
                  <?php
                      while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($rResultSet))
                     {
                   ?>

                  <td><?php echo $row['id']?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $row['name']?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $row['user_role']?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $row['start_date']?></td>
                  <td>

                  <form id='euser' action='edituser.php' method='post'>
                  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id']?>">
                  <input type="hidden" name="type" value="edituser">

                  <a  href="javascript: document.getElementById('euser').submit();">Edit</i></a>|
                 </form>
                 <?php 
                 }
                 ?>
```

result of this code

[image]

2.when click on Edit link every time first id which 16 throw by form

i need , when press link  edit at id 17 then id 17 thrown by form

Comment: What is the result now when you click **edit**?

Comment: Use class instead of id. `Id` value must be unique. So when you click on edit everytime it get the element id of first occurance of the form where `id="euser"` .

Comment: add any attribute for edit like this data-id=".$id."

Comment: at error log i check value which's 16 (first value all time) send by form

Comment: what you get when you click on Edit... i seen here you passed hidden.

Comment: Okay please try to print your id on that in link td. what its returns

Comment: like ????
 <a  href="javascript: document.getElementById('euser').submit();"><?php echo $row['id']?>Edit</i></a>|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below if it help :

```
<?php
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($rResultSet))
{
?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $row['id'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['name'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['user_role'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['start_date'];?></td>
<td>

    <form id='<?php echo $row['id'];?>' action='edituser.php' method='post'>
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id'];?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="type" value="edituser">

        <a  href="javascript: document.getElementById('<?php echo $row['id'];?>').submit();">Edit</a>|
    </form>
</td>
</tr>
 <?php 
   }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because of form's `id` attribute, it has to be unique for each row. Right now you're assigning the same id value `euser` for each row. For maintaining the uniqueness of `id` value, what you can do is, append the `$row['id']` with `euser` for each table row. Also, you forgot to encapsulate each table row in `<tr>...</tr>`. So your code should be like this:

```
<?php
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($rResultSet)){
    ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['id']?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['name']?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['user_role']?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['start_date']?></td>
            <td>

            <form id='euser<?php echo $row['id']?>' action='edituser.php' method='post'>
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id']?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="type" value="edituser">

                <a  href="javascript: document.getElementById('euser<?php echo $row['id']?>').submit();">Edit</i></a>|
            </form>
        <tr>
    <?php 
    }
?>
```